# Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a page with displays all the records of a mysql table namely fares in a tabular form . but it's showing the following message in browser

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
>   If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 404
>   localhost
>   Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.5.30

And here is my code:

```
<?php
include("dbCon.php");
if(isset($_POST['view'])) {
    $vquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fares ORDER BY sno ASC");
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($vquery)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['sno']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['destination']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['distance']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Express']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Luxury']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Volvo_ac']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Volvo_nac']."</td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: and here is my code

`<?php`
`include("dbCon.php");`
`if(isset($_POST['view']))`
`{`
`$vquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fares ORDER BY sno ASC");`
`echo "<table border='1'>";`
`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($vquery)){`
`echo "<tr>";`
`echo "<td>".$row['sno']."</td>";`
`echo "<td>".$row['destination']."</td>";`
`echo "<td>".$row['distance']."</td>";`
`echo "<td>".$row['Express']."</td>";`
`echo "<td>".$row['Luxury']."</td>";`
`echo "<td>".$row['Volvo_ac']."</td>";`
`echo "<td>".$row['Volvo_nac']."</td>";`
`}`
`echo "</table>";`
`}`
`?>`

Comment: Put the code in your question, **not** as a comment.

Comment: What's a the name of the script file? Where is it located? What's DOCUMENT_ROOT in the configuration of your apache? What URL do you enter in the browser's navbar?

Comment: 404 means file not found. Are  you sure the URL is correct?

Comment: filename is viewfares.php and it is located in htdocs folder in xampp

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated. You should **not** use them.

Comment: so what can we use in place of mysql_query

Comment: Either [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli_* functions](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php).

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment so posting as answer

Check the URL you're typing.

```
localhost/viewfares.php
```

should go in your URL, that error occurs when ppl usually forget the **.php**